# Javascript: override default javascript behaviour from different directions

Tags: javascript

i have 3 html pages

first page = homepage with 2 anchors (links) to the second and third page

second page = 1 anchor to third page

---

so.. first page and second page both has an anchor to the third page..

The third page's content has dynamic content. However the content differs from what the previous page was.

so i have a very simple html script for loading dynamic html:

```
<div class="thumbnail-panel row small-unstack">
    <script>insertModels();</script>
</div>
```

so how can i change the outcome of insertModels, based on its previous location?

Comment: "*the content differs from what the previous page was.*" - why would it be the same page then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.referrer` to find the URL the user visited to the page you are on. So place that as a parameter which takes a URL for `insertModels`:

```
<script>insertModels(document.referrer);</script>
```

Then modify the function with a `if-statement`:

```
insertModels = function(loc) {
    if( loc === "someCertainUrlHere" ) {
        // Code for spesific last location
    } else {
        // normal code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is your setup is as follows:

```
Page 1:
foo

Page 2:
bar

Page 3: from page 1:
foo bar

Page 3: from page 2:
bar foo
```

If this is the case then you can do this several ways.

First you could just create an .html page for each of the page 3 variations which actually aligns with the style of page delivery you are doing now.

```
Page 3: from page 1:

looks like Page 3: foo bar

Page 4: from page 2:

looks like Page 3: bar foo
```

Alternatively you could have a shell template that loads no matter what but includes it's own script that checks ( let say the url ) for a parameter then loads the secondary content of the page

```
Page 3: from page 1 ( url ?page1 )

if ( window.location.indexOf('page1') > -1 ) { // foo bar }


Page 3: from page 2 ( url ?page2 )

if ( window.location.indexOf('page2') > -1 ) { // bar foo }
```

Your third option is session storage

If you look at the documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

You can set variables in the browser and check them again when needed you can use this in a similar way to the second example:

```
Page 1:
sessionStorage.setItem("page", "1");

Page 2:
sessionStorage.setItem("page", "2");

Page 3:
if (parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("page")) === 1) {
// foo bar
}

Page 3:
if (parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("page")) === 2) {
// bar foo
}
```

Obviously this is all pseudo code but it should make sense. If you include more of the structure and setup of your project I may be able to extend my answer to fit your scenario more exactly.

Comment: i think im gonna use sessionStorage

Comment: @user3402571 if you edit my answer to include session storage and accept it it will be helpful to others

Comment: @user3402571 I added a session storage example hopefully this should help

Comment: @user3402571 Why? JavaScript have a specific variable to handle your exact problem. Sure you can use a session variable to keep track of the last visited page, but `document.referrer` already does that for you, and is more supported.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I think all of the answers are correct but I think user3402571 was a throw away account so I don't expect to see an accepted answer, If you want to edit my answer to include yours at the top  it will help others.

Comment: no.. what my idea is to keep the function call as it is.. and do a session check in the function itself..